# Compare FTP files with MD5

Tags: ftp, md5

I want to use **batch** to upload from the `mput` command to FTP. But, what I do not want to do is upload a file that has already been uploaded before, so I need the MD5 of each file and compare the new ones with the existing ones.

How are the commands I need?

Comment: Why not use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)? It's 2017 and FTP is like sending a fax.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure your remote server supports the checksum calculation at all. Many do not. I believe there's even no standard FTP command to calculate a checksum of a remote file. There were many proposals and there are many proprietary solutions.

The latest proposal is:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bryan-ftpext-hash-02

Some of the commands that can be used to calculate MD5 checksum are: `XMD5`, `MD5`, and `HASH`.

You can test that with WinSCP. The WinSCP supports all the previously mentioned commands. Test its [checksum calculation function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_properties#checksum) or the [`checksum` scripting command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_checksum). If they work, [enable logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging) and check, what command and what syntax WinSCP uses against your server.

Then you can execute the command in your command-line FTP client. You didn't tell us, what client are you using. In common Windows or *nix command-line `ftp` client, you can use `quote` command to execute an arbitrary FTP protocol command, like:

```
quote MD5 filename
```

If you are on Windows, you can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting). As in GUI, WinSCP will find out for you, what command to use. You simply use [`checksum` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_checksum):

```
checksum md5 index.html
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Though note, that you better use SHA-1. MD5 is not to be trusted anymore.